# Will writing a jagged array to a binary file yield different results than writing a multidimensional one with the same values?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, out-of-memory, binaryfiles

I had a C# multidimensional array that was too large and threw an outofmemory exception. So I changed my code and decided to use a jagged array `array[][][]` rather than my original `array[,,]`. When writing these to binary files (seen below):

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(File.OpenWrite($"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)}/array.bin"), array);
```

will the resulting file be different in any way? To add context, I will be trying to open these .bin files in ImageJ importing as raw data (to get a stack of images for volume rendering).

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: With the jagged array, importing into imagej yielded garbled data. I couldn't try with the 3d array because of the exception.

Comment: I'd suggest trying with a smaller array.